# Examples of printf returning -1 when using %C, %S, %ls, %lc

Tags: c, printf

I'm searching for examples of `printf` returning -1 when using the flags
`%C`, `%s`, `%ls`, and `%lc`. Or even the logic behind it.

I've looked on Wikipedia for UTF-8 and all the "bad utf-8 sequences" but even with those `printf` doesn't return -1.

So I tried the following code **[NEW TRY]**:

```
#import <stdlib.h>
#import <stdio.h>
int main() {
  // I ADDED THIS
  locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
  int result = printf("%lc", 0xff00);
  printf("%d", result);
  return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
＀
4
```

EDIT 2 : I'm on a unix environment

Comment: "even with those printf doesnt return -1."  Post the code used that failed to return -1.

Comment: C standard only says *"The printf function returns the number of characters transmitted, or a negative value if
an output or encoding error occurred."*. That's all. You need specify implementation you are using, since it's possible that some implementation *never* returns negative value.

Comment: Also, `%ls` expects `wchar_t *`, not `char *`. And it also expects null terminated string. Failing to do either results in *undefined behaviour*. Code is broken and you cannot reason with it.

Comment: @usr2564301 ok i changed example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small example:

```
#import <stdlib.h>
#import <stdio.h>
int main() {
  char* garbage = (char*)malloc(2);
  garbage[0] = 0xff;
  garbage[1] = 0x00;
  int result = printf("%ls", garbage);
  free(garbage);
  printf("%d", result);
  return 0;
}
```

`ff00` is not a valid unicode sequence. The logic behind needing it is that not all arbitrary sequence of bytes is a valid unicode string. Unicode spec says that `ff00` not valid. Thus, printf returns -1 when asked to print that it.

EDIT: you can also try with wchar_t and using 0xff00 and 0x0000 as the first and second shorts respectively (or 0xffff:0x0000 etc). printf will still return -1.

Comment: `ff00` is a valid UTF16 sequence.  It is not a valid UTF8 sequence

Comment: @Couteau This all depends on your compiler/runtime/environment. On Unix-like systems it will most likely just sends all bytes to the output without checking - this saves you performance.

Comment: You'r right i'm on a unix environment. Thanks for the edit